# OpenCV BOW - too high histogram values

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement BOW with OpenCV library in C++. I have extracted keypoints of images with SIFT method like this (for each image):

```
featureDetector->detect(image, keypoints);
descriptorExtractor->compute(image, keypoints, descriptors);
bowTrainer.add(descriptors);
```

then vocabulary is trained with `bowTrainer.cluster()` and stored into `BOWImgDescriptorExtractor bowDE`. After I've stored vocabulary a wanted to see at least one diagram for some of the images. This is implemented like this

```
featureDetector->detect(image, keypoints);
bowDE->compute(image, keypoints, histogram);
for (int i = 0; i < histogram.cols; i++)
    cout << histogram.at<unsigned>(0, i) << ",";
```

And the result has `1` row with `k` columns (`k` from k-means) values either `0` or sth around `980000000` I don't think this is correct, please tell me what am I doing wrong. This looks very bad when I want to show diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost forgot... Solution was pretty simple. Line:

```
cout << histogram.at<unsigned>(0, i) << ",";
```

had to be changed to

```
cout << histogram.at<float>(0, i) << ",";
```

because generated histogram is normalized histogram. for more detailed answer see [OpenCV forum answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/31565/print-histogram-values-for-image-in-bow/?answer=31576#post-id-31576)